# A lot of weird websites have linked to my domain, do I need to be careful?

Tags: seo, backlinks, spam-prevention

I recently found that a lot of (more than 30) websites are linking to my domain.

Those websites are mostly from India and there are hundreds of links on each page.

The content is "top websites" or something like that.

Here is an example:

[image]

Why is this happening? Do I need to be careful?

Does anybody have any insights on this?

Thanks,

Comment: I think this is pretty common.  I have similar links to my sites but it hasn't appeared to have had any impact on my site.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any thought about why they are creating such content on the internet?

Comment: I looked at two of the sites in the list, and one was firewall blocked the other was a shopping assistant. The shopping assistant was likely just a machine created link and the firewall was likely never intended to be published - just the owners person bookmarks? maybe? in HTML form?

Answer (score 2):

The last algo update on this subject was Monday, July 26, 2021, and the advice given by Google was to avoid attracting them to link to your site and don't link back to them.

> https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/07/link-tagging-and-link-spam-update
> Links are one of the ways Google understands what content may be helpful to searchers, and they can be good for sites to receive, as long as they're well deserved. A best practice is to avoid methods of acquiring links that violate our guidelines against link schemes. In particular, if you're linking out to other sites, make sure to qualify those links appropriately. Here are some more specific guidelines to help site owners manage links that involve payment, sponsorship, or are otherwise commercial in nature.

Don't link back to sites just because they link to you. The links on your site are under your control and if you link to a bad neighborhood you become part of that neighborhood.

What you can expect from google is that they nullify any value of those links once they find them, but it is unlikely they have any value. Some of them may be machine created pages which have made a copy of links from search engines or other sources in an effort to automatically create a page they think will rank ... but google and others actively work to remove that type of spam.

### Disavow tool

Google does have a disavow tool for incoming links, but most large sites can not keep up with all the spam links they receive. However, if the sites are ones you don't want your name associated with ... you can use google's disavow tool to help in removing that type of spam.

If the link has increased your site ranking such gains will be short lived. Link schemes are not going to allow a site to remain profitable, Google will insure that, they ultimately crash and burn.

### Negative SEO

Negative SEO is the term used for when somebody tries to sabotage another site. Google is aware of this and looks to the site to see if the site in question links back to the bad neighborhood. Disavow such links when you see them, to let google know, I'm not in their neighborhood. But I expect most of these sites are machine created.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked your domain using majestic, i didn't find those but i've found a lot of domain from "the globe". It's the main spamming bakclinks on the world, so you don't have to loose time or mind thinking about it : google know how to ignore them.

What is a bad backlinks ?
1/ To be bad it need to be dofollow, some of those spamming links are no follow, so just ignore them, no matter the anchor or the site they come from.

2/ It had made your website decrease in ranking. If it didn't it 's probably google did ignore them

3/ It has spamming anchor (X rated, religion or orther unsafe words, illegal stuff and so on)

4/ it come from X rated, religion or orther unsafe words, illegal stuff website.

5/ the source page is indexed in google (use inurl: to check)

6/ You can see this backlink in the Google search console, google has indexed it

If it doesn't correspond to this guide, it's just another spam link that will stay in your backlink report in your favorite monitoring tool

Hope it'll help

Comment: > I've just checked your domain using majestic
Just wondering, how do you know my domain?

Comment: Just thought it was the first one in green but because of this question I guess it wasn't ? (Tell me so I edit the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to be careful/mindful of it, but the impact depends on the quality, relevance and purpose of those sites.  If they are low quality or irrelevant, or, worse, spammy you should disavow them In google, but if they are related and not spammy they are unlikely to hurt.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to "disavow them In google"?

Comment: Google says that [you should disavow links only if they have caused or are about to cause a manual action on your site.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/136828/54214)

Comment: Sadly, domain property is not supported by this tool.